# Python JSON: No me deja imprimir la data de mi JSON

Tags: python, json

Empece hoy a leer paginas web y ver videos sobre JSON con Python, y para probar lo que he aprendido hice 2 archivos de prueba:

- main.py
- data.json

Hice este pedazo de codigo en main.py:

```
import json;

dir = 'C:....\data.json'

with open(dir) as content:
    data = json.loads(dir.read())
    print(data);
```

Y me sale este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado buscando tutoriales en youtube y no le he podido resolver aun ¿Que esta mal?

Gracias de antemano.

EDIT: Este es el json ¿Esta mal?

```
[
    {
        "nombre" : "Maria",
        "apellido" : "Eugenia (el apellido y nombre es falso)" 
    }
]
```

Comment: 1. no utilices palabras reservadas como nombre de variables 2. te has confundido de variable, debe ser `content.read()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es principalmente que a lo que haces `.read()` es un string, no es la información de tu archivo, por lo que tu tratas de hacer un json desde un string sin formato válido.

```
import json;

dir = 'C:....\data.json'

with open(dir) as content:
    data = json.loads(content.read())#Solo este cambio es
    print(data);
```

Recuerda que colocar `with` te ayuda a minimizar otras variables, pero no significa que se sobre escriben, para eso tienes la parte derecha `as <miVariable>:` puedes verlo como, traducido literal, `Con abrir(ruta) llamado contenido:` por lo que dentro de tu lógica, la información estará en la variable contenido(content), según el ejemplo en español

Comment: `with` es con *context manager* que sirve/ayuda a especificar el comportamiento en ese bloque de código. No minimiza el uso de variables

Comment: @Christian Gracias, eres mas claro... Yo cuando uso el with, lo veo como quitarme partes del codigo, por ejemplo cuando abro un archivo, no tengo que cerrarlo, recuerdo primordial jajajaja

Comment: 1) Muy bien ¿Y cual seria la solucion? 2) Si el with lo puse porque la gran mayoria de los tutoriales que he visto lo utilizan, pero realmente no se para que se una el with

Comment: @Skeletoos57 la solución es poner `json.loads(content.read())`  En cuanto al `with` ya he dicho que es (de forma muuuuyyy simplificada) pero si quieres puedo darte una respuesta y profundizar sobre lo que es